# How do I upgrade my Slicable trait to satisfy the borrow checker in repeated calls

Tags: rust, traits, borrow-checker

I have an IO library that has a big `State` struct and I am writing a function that requires two phases.
In the first phase, only the reader class is touched, but the call-site chooses a read-only table slice to pass in.

In the second phase, the whole `State` struct is modified but the read-only table is no longer needed.

I've split the function into two functions--and that works, but when I try to combine those functions, the borrow checker breaks down when I replace a concrete `Vector` class with a custom trait `Slicable`

Is there any way to make `process_with_table_fn` operate on `Slicable` values in the State struct rather than directly on Vectors?

tl;dr I'd like fn `what_i_want_to_work` to compile, but instead I have only gotten `what_works` to build. Is my trait definition for `Slicable` badly crafted for this use case? Why does the concrete type operate better than the trait?

```
pub struct MemReader {
    buf : [u8; 1024],
    off : usize,
}
pub struct Vector<'a> {
   buf : &'a [u32],
}
trait Slicable {
   fn slice(self : &Self) -> &[u32];

}
impl<'a> Slicable for Vector<'a> {
   fn slice(self : &Self) -> &[u32]{
       return self.buf;
   }
}
impl MemReader {
    fn read(self : &mut Self, how_much : usize, output : &mut u8) -> bool {
        if self.off + how_much > self.buf.len() {
            return false;
        }
        self.off += how_much;
        *output = self.buf[self.off - 1];
        return true;
    }
}

pub struct State<'a> {
   pub mr : MemReader,
   pub translation_tables : [Vector<'a>; 4],
   pub other_tables : [Vector<'a>; 4],
   pub state : i32,
}

fn process_first(mr : &mut MemReader, table : &[u32]) -> (bool, u32) {
    let mut temp : u8 = 0;
    let ret = mr.read(8, &mut temp);
    if !ret {
        return (false, 0);
    }
    return (true, table[temp as usize]);
}

fn process_second(s : &mut State, ret_index : (bool, u32), mut outval : &mut u8) -> bool {
    let (ret, index) = ret_index;
    if ! ret {
        return false;
    }
    s.state += 1;
    return s.mr.read(index as usize, &mut outval);
}

pub fn process_with_table_fn(mut s : &mut State, table : &[u32], mut outval : &mut u8) -> bool {
    let ret = process_first(&mut s.mr, table);
    return process_second(&mut s, ret, &mut outval);
}

macro_rules! process_with_table_mac(
    ($state : expr, $table : expr, $outval : expr) => {
        process_second(&mut $state, process_first(&mut $state.mr, &$table), &mut $outval)
    };
);

pub fn what_works(mut s : &mut State) {
   let mut outval0 : u8 = 0;
   let _ret0 = process_with_table_fn(&mut s, &s.other_tables[2].buf[..], &mut outval0);
}

/*
pub fn what_i_want_to_work(mut s : &mut State) {
   let mut outval0 : u8 = 0;
   let ret0 = process_with_table_fn(&mut s, s.other_tables[2].slice(), &mut outval0);

   // OR

   let mut outval1 : u8 = 0;
   //let ret1 = process_with_table_mac!(s, s.other_tables[2].slice(), outval1);
}
*/


fn main() {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two things going on. Lets look at your trait implementation first:

```
impl<'a> Slicable for Vector<'a> {
   fn slice(self : &Self) -> &[u32]{
       return self.buf;
   }
}
```

The method's signature is expanded to

```
fn slice<'b>(self : &'b Self) -> &'b[u32]
```

which means that the lifetime of the resulting slice is shorter than the lifetime of `self`. At the call site, this means that `s.other_tables[2].slice()` borrows `s` while `&s.other_tables[2].buf[..]` borrows something that has lifetime `'a`, completely ignoring the lifetime of `s`. To replicate this behavior, you can add a lifetime to your trait:

```
trait Slicable<'a> {
   fn slice(self: &Self) -> &'a [u32];
}

impl<'a> Slicable<'a> for Vector<'a> {
   fn slice(self: &Self) -> &'a [u32] {
       self.buf
   }
}
```

Now you should be set, but the compiler still has a minor limitation with respect to method call lifetimes, so you need to split your call into two lines:

```
let slice = s.other_tables[2].slice();
let ret0 = process_with_table_fn(&mut s, slice, &mut outval0);
```